# How to "Correctly" Comment a program, using different commenting styles and when to use them?

Tags: java, code-cleanup, comments

After spending a long time writing (what I like to think of as a nice program), I'm looking to clean up my code, and do some commenting so that its easy to read and looks nice and crisp.

My question is, when do I use the different types of commenting? 
Block, Single Line, JavaDoc, etc.

For example, if you take my code (just one method). How would I go about commenting it "correctly"

```
public static String decipher(String cipherText, String key,
        String originalKey) {

    String cipher = cipherText;
    String plainText;
    int currentLetter;
    int cl = 0;

    StringBuilder deciphered = new StringBuilder();

    while (deciphered.length() != key.length()) {

        for (int x = 0; x < cipherText.length(); x++) {
            String plaintextVal;
            Character cipherChar = cipherText.charAt(x);
            Character keyChar = key.charAt(x);
            String currentCipherLetter = cipherChar.toString();
            String currentKeyLetter = keyChar.toString();
            int cipherVal = letters.indexOf(currentCipherLetter) + 1;
            int keyVal = letters.indexOf(currentKeyLetter) + 1;
            if (cipherVal - keyVal < 0) {
                int negativeVal = cipherVal - keyVal;
                plaintextVal = letters.get((cipherVal - keyVal - 1) + 26);

            } else if (cipherVal - keyVal - 1 < 0 && cipherVal - keyVal > 0) {
                plaintextVal = letters.get(0);

            } else if (cipherVal - keyVal == 0) {
                plaintextVal = letters.get(25);
            } else {
                plaintextVal = letters.get(cipherVal - keyVal - 1);
            }

            deciphered.append(plaintextVal);

        }

    }

    plainText = deciphered.toString();
    System.out.println(cipherText + "/" + originalKey + " = " + plainText);
    return plainText;
}
```

Also, if you could give me an example of WHAT I should actually write in these comments, I don't exactly know what is not needed(useless info) vs Useful commenting.     If you write a commented example with my code, just guess what the functions do.

All help/suggestions is appreciated. Hopefully this question can help people in the future as well.

Thanks,
Sully

Comment: @JoshM I wrote the code and completely understand it. What I'm not fully grasping is how exactly I should go about commenting it so that its deemed clean and useful in the best way possible

Comment: Simple methods like this should not need any comments. You should however run your code through some static analysis tools e.g. FindBugs etc. as you have unused variables or scopes that can be reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write what another developer needs to know, concisely as possible, in the case that you get hit by a bus.

Or for a year from now, when you need to refactor the whole thing, what *you* need to *not* have to relearn everything.

See this:

[Technical tips for writing great Javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398546/technical-tips-for-writing-great-javadoc)